# path to php in regex

Tags: php, regex

I am currently working at a project involving regex in php. I wanted to know why or how can I get this recursive regular expression to work in PHP:

```
{{test":"([a-f0-9]{32})"},{"test2":"([a-z]{3})}}
And the given results should be an array with:

[a-f0-9]{32}
[a-z]{3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, this regex helps

```
/.sample.\/.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)-/
```

You should escape the . or it will mean any character.
If it does not matter, what is after the dash, you need not use the anchor $ for end of string.

This finds the first occurence of number in the string, because .*? is not eager. It matches only as much as necessary for the rest of the pattern.

You can use this, if between / and the number are only letters allowed:

```
/.sample.\/[a-zA-Z]*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)-/
```